# jquery appending class to a class

Tags: jquery

ok I have a `<ul id="classname"></ul>` can i insert '`<li id="classname1"></li>`' inside ul on form load using jquery ?

Comment: That's an ID, not a class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#classname").append('<li id="classname1"></li>');
});
```

Note that this is valid once, as an ID should be unique, if you actually meant classes, e.g.
`<ul class="classname"><li class="classname1"></li></ul>`, then you'd do this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".classname").append('<li class="classname1"></li>');
});
```